# Do 2 consecutive ajax requests, one that changes content from the first ajax request

Tags: ajax

I have this Ajax functions that changes one section of the website with a div that has the id of content, then once this method is executed there will be lots of newer divs nested inside, one of these divs will have the id of main_section, this div will be changed in the following ajax method for some new section.

This code executes both in the network section of chrome debugger, but only the first section appears to have executed in the website.

In brief, what should I change to make the second section change one part of the section that is created with the first ajax request?

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/pizzas',
        type: 'GET', 
        async: false , 
        success: function (data) {
            $('#content').html(data);
        }
    }).done(function (response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/pizzas/'+ pizza_id + '/edit/',
            type: 'GET',
            async: false , 
            data: {
                pizzaID: '{{ $pizza->id }}'
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#main_section').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: What does your html look like? Does `#main_section` rely on `#content` loaded with the previous ajax call?

Comment: Once you replace #content by the first ajax, this will contain a div called #main_section that will then be changed by the second ajax method. So yes  #main_section relies on #content after the first ajax is executed.

Comment: The nesting you have should work. Verify the network requests are successful, you don't have script errors, and the id are unique in the page. Since these are GET requests, make sure you're not getting a cached result (which may not be what you think it ought to be).